# Escaping underscore in SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis, sms

I have an SSIS expression.as per below:
I am sending the results of this package as an sms,however the sms does not show the underscores,I have therefore opted to using dashes for now.

The sms is showing at as OLEGALINITTEST

I there a way i can escape the underscore so that it shows on the sms?

REPLACE(@[System::PackageName], "_", "-") =  O-LEGAL-INIT-TEST

Desired output is O_LEGAL_INIT_TEST

I am replacing the underscore's in the string with "-" dashes .I am sending the variable to an Oracle package that send the actual sms.

Comment: Did you try replacing the underscores with a backslash-underscore sequence? `REPLACE(@[System::PackageName], "_", "\_")` Might work.

Comment: Yes, I tried that.It does not work ,error on evaluating the expression "use of illegal charater \ ". Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`@[System::PackageName]` is generally the same as the file name without the file extension so given a package named `This-Is-Fun.dtsx` we would expect to see the PackageName property as `This-Is-Fun`.

But, there are cases where this not the case. If we named our package `A=B.C_D.dtsx`, the resulting object name for our package is `A B C_D`. Each offending character is replaced with spaces.

If you attempt to name an SSIS object with "something weird" it will throw an error on the operation like

> The name cannot contain any of the following characters: / \ : [ ] . =

The restrictions are similar, but different, for the package name itself as Windows/Visual Studio will balk with

> contain any of the following characters: / ? : & \ * " < > | # %
>
> contain Unicode control characters contain invalid surrogate
>
> characters be system reserved names, including 'CON', 'AUX', 'PRN', 'COM1'
>
> or 'LPT2' be '.' or '..'

As always with expressions in SSIS, check what you're building. Create an SSIS Variable where you specify an expression.

Assuming you create an SSIS variable called `SMS_CONTENT` data type of string and then I'm going to replace spaces with underscores. The expression is

```
REPLACE(@[System::PackageName], " ", "_")
```

Given a starting package name of

- a=b.SO_61618859_This_Is_Fun.dtsx
- System::PackageName becomes `a b SO_61618859_This_Is_Fun`
- SMS_CONTENT becomes `a_b_SO_61618859_This_Is_Fun`

If it works fine during development but goes awry in production, log the value via a script task's information event so you can review logs after the run. https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html You don't need to Biml it, just mark the variable as part of the Read only variable collection and the following script will record the values in the log. In your case, I'd add System::PackageName and then my SSIS variable, User::SMS_CONTENT

```
bool fireAgain = false;
string message = "{0}::{1} : {2}";
foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
{
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
}
```

Comment: Once you have verified what you are sending to your Oracle method is as expected, I can't help you but SSIS stuff, I'm happy to help you through some weirdness